# How to convert a pygame image to Open CV image?

Tags: opencv, pygame, kinect-v2, pykinect

I am currently getting a real time RGB video from a Kinect2 camera using Pygame and pykinect2. I want to convert it into an open cv image so that it would be helpful for me in my further Computations.

```
import pykinect2
import pygame
import cv2
import ctypes
from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2
from pykinect2 import PyKinectRuntime
kinectcam = PyKinectRuntime.PyKinectRuntime(PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Color)
def draw_color_frame(frame, target_surface):
    target_surface.lock()
    address = kinectcam.surface_as_array(target_surface.get_buffer())
    ctypes.memmove(address, frame.ctypes.data, frame.size)
    del address
    target_surface.unlock()

pygame.init()
frame_surface = pygame.Surface((kinectcam.color_frame_desc.Width, kinectcam.color_frame_desc.Height), 0, 32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Kinect View")
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w >> 1, infoObject.current_h >> 1),
                            pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE, 32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE: # window resized
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], 
                                               pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE, 32)

    if kinectcam.has_new_color_frame():
        frame = kinectcam.get_last_color_frame()
        draw_color_frame(frame, frame_surface)
        frame = None   
    h_to_w = float(frame_surface.get_height()) / frame_surface.get_width()
    target_height = int(h_to_w * screen.get_width())
    surface_to_draw = pygame.transform.scale(frame_surface, (screen.get_width(), target_height));
    screen.blit(surface_to_draw, (0,0))
    surface_to_draw = None
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
kinectcam.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pyKinect2 library, you can create an acquisitionClass.py which defines different methods and properties required for Kinect frame processing. Then call the acquisitionClass.py which contains the **get_color_frame()** that does the conversion, from your main script (Run.py) to use and display the converted color frame to opencv frame as follows:

**Note:** I'm answering this assuming you do not want to use the pyGame library but OpenCV instead.

**Run.py**

```
import cv2
from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2
from pykinect2.PyKinectV2 import *
from pykinect2 import PyKinectRuntime
from acquisitionKinect import AcquisitionKinect
from frame import Frame

if __name__ == '__main__':

    kinect = AcquisitionKinect()
    frame = Frame()

    while True:
        kinect.get_frame(frame)
        kinect.get_color_frame()
        image = kinect._frameRGB
        #OpenCv uses RGB image, kinect returns type RGBA, remove extra dim.
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB) 

        if not image is None:
            cv2.imshow("Output-Keypoints",image) 

        cv2.waitKey(30)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break
```

**acquisitionKinect.py**

```
import ctypes
import _ctypes
import sys

if sys.hexversion >= 0x03000000:
    import _thread as thread
else:
    import thread

class AcquisitionKinect():
    #Create a constructor to initialize different types of array and frame objects
    def __init__(self, resolution_mode=1.0):
    self.resolution_mode = resolution_mode

    self._done = False

    # Kinect runtime object, we want only color and body frames
    self._kinect = PyKinectRuntime.PyKinectRuntime(PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Color | PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Body | PyKinectV2.FrameSourceTypes_Depth)

    # here we will store skeleton data
    self._bodies = None
    self.body_tracked = False
    self.joint_points = np.array([])
    self.joint_points3D = np.array([])
    self.joint_points_RGB = np.array([])
    self.joint_state = np.array([])

    self._frameRGB = None
    self._frameDepth = None
    self._frameDepthQuantized = None
    self._frameSkeleton = None
    self.frameNum = 0

    def get_frame(self, frame):
        self.acquireFrame()
        frame.ts = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        self.frameNum += 1

        frame.frameRGB = self._frameRGB
        frame.frameDepth = self._frameDepth
        frame.frameDepthQuantized = self._frameDepthQuantized
        frame.frameSkeleton = self._frameSkeleton

    #Get a color frame object
    def get_color_frame(self):
       self._frameRGB = self._kinect.get_last_color_frame()
       self._frameRGB = self._frameRGB.reshape((1080, 1920,-1)).astype(np.uint8)
       self._frameRGB = cv2.resize(self._frameRGB, (0,0), fx=1/self.resolution_mode, fy=1/self.resolution_mode)

    #Acquire the type of frame required
    def acquireFrame(self):
        if self._kinect.has_new_color_frame():
            self.get_color_frame()

    def close(self):
        self._kinect.close()
        self._frameDepth = None
        self._frameRGB = None
        self._frameSkeleton = None
```

**Frame.py**

```
class Frame():
    frameRGB = None
    frameDepth = None
    frameDepthQuantized = None
    frameSkeleton = None
    frame_num = 0
    shoulder_orientation_euler = None
    shoulder_orientation_quat = None
```

Comment: How can I modify the above code to get the depth frame aswell?

Comment: It can be called just like the color frame, here is the entire implementation of acquisitionKinect.py at this github link: https://github.com/gdubrg/wrapperPyKinect2

Comment: I have modified the Run.py program to fetch a depth frame, but it is not getting visible on to my screen. I am not able to find out where I am going wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I assume your are trying to convert the image you are blitting (surface_to_draw). To convert pygame.Surface object to opencv image:

```
#  create a copy of the surface
view = pygame.surfarray.array3d(surface_to_draw)

#  convert from (width, height, channel) to (height, width, channel)
view = view.transpose([1, 0, 2])

#  convert from rgb to bgr
img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(view, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Update: I also assumed your pygame image is color image.